# How to get http post request body without property in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am creating an API. Where I have to accept JSON data. I found the JSON not properly fit with my property class. In this scenario how should I get data from post request?

[image]

I have tried with WEB API but it's showing null error
**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance** of an object.'

[image]

Comment: Change the class so it matches json the endpoint should accept.

Comment: Hi Guys,
Could you please check now and help me for the solution.

Comment: You have a null reference exception. That's not the same problem "I can't parse my json because it has different properties"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot always change the class like @GuruStron suggests. Because it could have dependencies on other parts of the program.

What you should do : **Customize your JSON parser**

You probably already use `Newtonsoft` to parse your incoming body request into your class. Now what you need is to customize that parser so it fit your need.

Here is the doc: [How to create a custom JsonCoverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

If you don't use `Newtonsoft` you probably use default `System.TextJson` in that case [here are the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

No matter which "parser" you use, you'll probably find an equivalent on the web

**Please provide more details (and some code) for a more precise answer.**

Comment: _"Because it could have dependencies on other parts of the program."_ - then you just introduce a DTO =)

Comment: _"You probably already use Newtonsoft to parse your incoming body request into your class"_ - or not, since this is marked with `.NET Core` tag and recent editions of ASP.NET Core use System.Text.Json

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are receiving the json via an HttpClient, but in the case you can use ExpandoObject or dynamic as read target from the content.

es.

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<dynamic>();
```

or

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ExpandoObject>();
```

In any case, case the deserialization to dynamic or ExpandoObject could work also from a string (see [this](https://www.iditect.com/guide/csharp/csharp_howto_deserialize_json_into_dynamic_object.html#:%7E:text=How%20to%20deserialize%20JSON%20in%20to%20dynamic%20object,3%203.%20Use%20third-party%20library%20Json.NET%20from%20Newtonsoft.Json.)).

Comment: I don't recommend using dynamic, it's a pretty bad practice.